# How to pass data into fragment dynamically loaded into current activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

My activity contains "FrameLayout" element only.

In its 'onCreate' method I dynamically load fragment:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        UsersListFragment fragment = new UsersListFragment();

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        ft.commit();
}
```

On some event my fragment communicates back to activity and I need to instantiate another fragment and pass some data to it. I do it in the activity by implementing special interface that is in turn called by fragment. It looks like this way:

```
@Override
public void onUserSelected(long userId) {

        UserDetailsFragment fragment = new UserDetailsFragment();

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();

        fragment.updateUser(userId);
}
```

As a result, "fragment.updateUser(userId);" is called way to early (fragment is not initialized yet, it is not attached to activity).

Question: what is the proper way to pass data into the fragment?

Thanks a lot in advance. Any thoughts are greatly appreciated.

P.S. I've seen a lot of examples that show how to load fragments, but was not able to find those that show how to pass data...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That usually happens to me: once wrote a question I got a new idea to try...

Looks like one of the possible options is to **pass data by setting them via 'setArguments' method**... and use during 'onCreateView' fragment method...

Any better options?

Comment: Sounds good to me to use setArguments and use getArguments in onCreate in Fragment

Comment: Thanks, will take it as an answer, but any other ideas are more than welcome!

Comment: in setArguments we can pass bundle in which we can set the int, float, boolean and data of these type, can we pass RelativeLayout in bundle? And how can we pass RelativeLayout in fragment?

Comment: Do you want to pass whole layout? Don't think that is a good idea. You better pass data and inflate layout with those data